# terraform init creating a new workspace in automation

Tags: terraform

I have looked on the Internets but did not find anything close to an answer.
I have the following main.tf :

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "my-organization"

    workspaces {
      tags = ["app:myapplication"]
      
    }
  }
}
```

I am using terraform cloud and I would like to use workspace in automation.
In order to so, i need first to do a terraform init :

> /my/path # terraform init
>
> Initializing Terraform Cloud...
>
> No workspaces found.
>
> There are no workspaces with the configured tags
> (app:myapplication)   in your Terraform Cloud
> organization. To finish initializing, Terraform needs at   least one
> workspace available.
>
> Terraform can create a properly tagged workspace for you now. Please
> enter a   name to create a new Terraform Cloud workspace.
>
> Enter a value:

I would like to do something of the kind :

```
terraform init -workspace=my-workspace
```

so that it is created if it does not exist. But I do not find anything. The only way to create a the first workspace is manually.

How to do that in automation with ci/cd?

[edit]
terraform workspace commands are not available before init

> /src/terraform # terraform workspace list
>
> Error: Terraform Cloud initialization required: please run "terraform
> init"
>
> Reason: Initial configuration of Terraform Cloud.
>
> Changes to the Terraform Cloud configuration block require
> reinitialization, to discover any changes to the available workspaces.
>
> To re-initialize, run:    terraform init
>
> Terraform has not yet made changes to your existing configuration or
> state.

Comment: Well, you could do `terraform workspace list`, grep for the one you want to check is present, followed by `terraform workspace new <workspace-name>`. That would of course come before running the init step.

Comment: I cannot do terraform workspace command before the terraform init

Comment: Ok, what can you do?

Comment: Yoann and @MarkoE CLI and Cloud workspaces are not the same. Please see note here for explanation: https://www.terraform.io/cli/workspaces#managing-workspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the TF Cloud/TFE API. You are using TF Cloud, but can modify the endpoint to target your installation to use TFE.

You first need to [list the TF Cloud Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/cloud-docs/api-docs/workspaces#list-workspaces):

```
curl \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" \
  https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/organizations/my-organization/workspaces
```

where `my-organization` is your TF Cloud organization. This will return the workspaces in a JSON format. You would then need to parse the JSON and iterate over the maps/hashes/dictionaries of existing TF Cloud workspaces. For each iteration, inside the `data` and then the `name` key would be the nested value for the name of the workspace. You would gather the names of the workspaces and check that against the name of the workspace you want to exist. If the desired workspace does not exist in the list of workspaces, then you [create the TF Cloud workspace](https://www.terraform.io/cloud-docs/api-docs/workspaces#create-a-workspace):

```
curl \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" \
  --request POST \
  --data @payload.json \
  https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/organizations/my-organization/workspaces
```

again substituting with your organization and your specific payload. You can then `terraform init` successfully with the backend specifying the Tf Cloud workspace.

Note that if you are executing this in automation as you specify in the question, then the build agent needs connectivity to TF Cloud.

Comment: wow! thanks a lot I was hoping for something a bit more.. humm less tricky. But I guess this is the way with Hashicorp Terraform. Thansk a lot!

Comment: @Yoann Upvote/accept the answer since it solved your question please and thank you.

Comment: For what it's worth, that `terraform init` prompt to enter a workspace name leads to Terraform CLI making essentially the same API request as the second one in this answer, so there should be no functional difference between these two. `terraform init` is acting as an human-oriented interactive UI for that API, but if you're intending to automate anyway then it's simpler to cut Terraform CLI out of mix altogether and just use the API directly.

Comment: Another option, if you have some systematic conventions for your workspaces, would be to manage your Terraform Cloud workspaces using Terraform itself, with the `hashicorp/tfe` provider. That is yet another wrapper around that same API, and could be helpful if you need to do this on an ongoing/repeatable basis, rather than just as a one-off as `terraform init` is intended to handle here.

Comment: thanks to you @MartinAtkins. Such a pity the terraform cli not mirroring well the granularity of its API.

Answer (score 0):

I will not mark this as the answer, but I finally did this, which look like a bad trick to me :

```
export TF_WORKSPACE=myWorkspace
if terraform init -input=false; then echo "already exist"; else (sleep2; echo $TF_WORKSPACE) | terraform init; fi

terraform apply -auto-approve -var myvar=boo
```